# why rx-java zip code failed

Tags: java, rx-java2

Here is test code

```
    final Flowable<Integer> f1 = Flowable.fromPublisher(s -> {
        s.onNext(Integer.valueOf(1));
        s.onComplete();
    });


    final Flowable<Integer> f2 = Flowable.fromPublisher(s -> {
        s.onNext(Integer.valueOf(2));
        s.onComplete();
    });

    Flowable.zip(f1, f2, (i1, i2) -> "" + i1 + i2)
            .blockingSubscribe(System.out::println);
```

It will get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableZip$ZipSubscriber.onNext(FlowableZip.java:386)
```

I don't understand why?

And if I update code like this

```
    final Flowable<Integer> f1 = Flowable.<Integer>fromPublisher(s -> {
        s.onNext(Integer.valueOf(1));
        s.onComplete();
    }).onErrorResumeNext(Flowable.empty());


    final Flowable<Integer> f2 = Flowable.<Integer>fromPublisher(s -> {
        s.onNext(Integer.valueOf(2));
        s.onComplete();
    }).onErrorResumeNext(Flowable.empty());

    Flowable.zip(f1, f2, (i1, i2) -> "" + i1 + i2)
            .blockingSubscribe(System.out::println);
```

It will print 12 as expected. but why? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think I am wrong with backpressure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're breaking the contract of `Publisher<T>` with your use of `fromPublisher`.

Publishers need to behave in a very specific way as specified in the `Reactive Streams` contract. That behavior includes calling `Subscriber.onSubscribe()` BEFORE making any other calls and respecting the backpressure on that subscriber.

Because you don't call `onSubscribe` the internal `queue` variable never gets initialized and the call to `queue.offer` in its `onNext` method causes an NPE.

Presumably by using `onErrorResumeNext` the implementation ensures everything is properly called, 'fixing' the invalid state.

To fix your problem there are two possibilities:

1. Do not use `Flowable.fromPublisher`. It is meant to bridge from other implementations of the Reactive Streams manifesto and does not have any safeguards. Instead use `Flowable.create` which correctly handles initialization and backpressure.
2. Use the non-backpressure aware `Observable` since your usecase does not seem to concern itself with backpressure. Once again use the `Observable.create` method for safe usage.